# Swift error: (int) not convertible to int

Tags: swift

I am going through the "Swift Programming Language" guide from Apple and came across the following issue. The book defines a sumation function as:

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    var s = 0
    for number in numbers {
        s += number
    }
    return s
}
```

and includes an experiment to "write a function that calculates the average of it's arguments", which I am trying to re-use sumOf to define:

```
func averageOf(numbers: Int...) -> Float {
    var sum = sumOf(numbers)
    return Float(sum)/Float(numbers.count)
}
```

Xcode is returning an error calling sumOf(numbers): "'[Int]' not convertible to 'Int'" 
Ignoring the obvious divide by zero issue, why do variadic parameters lose their type inside the method and is there a way to cast this in a way to pass the variadic parameter to the sumOf function?

Comment: To the down voters of this question… it seems perfectly reasonable to be surprised you can’t pass a variadic argument into another variadic function. Just because it’s obvious to you doesn’t mean it’s a bad question.

Comment: (I did not downvote, however ...) some research can be expected before posting a question, and searching for "sumOf" in the Swift category would have lead to the solution quickly.

Comment: that’s fair, but that is what flagging is for. I suspect the votes were of the “this question is stupid” variety...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way variadic arguments work is that while the caller is able to pass any number of individual arguments one by one:

```
sumOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

they are presented inside the function as an array:

```
sumOf(numbers: Int…) {
    // numbers is of type [Int]
    // (you can see this by option-clicking numbers in Xcode)
}
```

That way the function implementor can tell how many there are, loop over them etc.

But that means you can’t call one variadic function using the variadic argument of another function.  The `sumOf` function wants multiple arguments of type `Int`, e.g. `1, 2, 3, 4`, but you are passing in one array argument of type `[Int]` e.g `[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

This is actually kind of a pain because there is no “splat” functionality in Swift – the ability to turn an array into a tuple.  So you can’t easily re-use your `sumOf` function as you’d like.

One solution to this is to implement `sumOf` twice: once as a function that takes an array:

```
func sumOf(numbers: [Int]) -> Int {
    // an alternative to the for loop
    // you might want to try...
    return reduce(numbers, 0, +)
}
```

And once as a variadic function:

```
func sumOf(numbers: Int...) -> Int {
    // don’t reimplement sumOf, just
    // call the array version
    return sumOf(numbers)
}
```

Then you can call it either way:

```
sumOf(1,2,3)
sumOf([1,2,3])
```

and Swift’s function overload resolution will pick the appropriate version.

Now your `averageOf` implementation, which was otherwise perfectly fine, will work, because it can use the array version of `sumOf`.

(if you want extra problems: try overloading `averageOf` the same way, and then maybe try writing versions of `sumOf` and `averageOf` that work on any integer type using generics :)

Answer (score 2):

When you pass `numbers` you're passing a single item of type `[Int]`.  What the variadic signature wants is some number of individual `Int`s that it packages into an array.

Similarly, you can write `sumOf(1, 2, 3, 4)` but not `sumOf([1, 2, 3, 4])`.